# Get x and y magnitude given a vector

Tags: integration, derivatives, trigonometry, vector-spaces, vectors

[image]

I have read an article at https://www.kjmagnetics.com/blog.asp?p=dipole.

How do we derive the Bx and By from B(r)?

Comment: Well, the $x$ component of $\hat{r}$ is $\sin(\theta)$, and the $y$ component is $\cos(\theta)$. What happens if you substitute these into the expression for $B(r)$?

Comment: @Bungo, if we consider x-component, since you have r times r, it would be sin^2(θ) ?

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\uvec}[1]{\boldsymbol{\hat{\textbf{#1}}}}$
Given that the direction of $\vec{m}$ is along $Y$ axis, so let $\vec{m}=m \uvec j$ where $m=|\vec m|$

From the figure, $\vec r= |\vec r| \cos(90°-\theta) \uvec i+ |\vec r| \cos{\theta} \uvec j \implies \vec r= |\vec r| \sin{\theta} \uvec i+ |\vec r| \cos{\theta} \uvec j $

$\therefore \uvec r=\sin{\theta} \uvec i + \cos {\theta} \uvec j$

Now, $$\uvec r. \vec m =(\sin{\theta} \uvec i + \cos {\theta} \uvec j).(m \uvec j) =m \cos{\theta}$$

So, $$(\uvec r. \vec m) \uvec r= m \cos{\theta} \uvec r= m \cos{\theta} \sin{\theta} \uvec i + m \cos^2{\theta} \uvec j$$

Hence, $$B(\vec{r})=\frac{\mu_0[3\uvec{r}(\uvec{r} .\vec{m})-\vec{m}]}{4\pi r^3}$$
$$ \implies B(\vec{r})=\frac{\mu_0[3 m \cos{\theta} \sin{\theta} \uvec i + 3 m \cos^2{\theta} \uvec j-m \uvec j]}{4\pi r^3} $$

$$ \implies B(\vec{r})=\frac{\mu_0 m}{4 \pi r^3}[3\cos{\theta} \sin{\theta} \uvec i +  (3 \cos^2{\theta} -1) \uvec j]$$

$$ \implies B(\vec{r})=\frac{\mu_0 m}{4\pi r^3} [3 \cos{\theta} \sin{\theta}] \uvec i + \frac{\mu_0 m}{4\pi r^3}[3 \cos^2{\theta} -1] \uvec j$$
Thus, component of field strength along $x$ axis is given by $B_x=\frac{\mu_0 m}{4\pi r^3} [3 \cos{\theta} \sin{\theta}]$

and component of field strength along $y$ axis is given by $B_y= \frac{\mu_0 m}{4\pi r^3}[3 \cos^2{\theta} -1]$

$B(\vec r)= B_x \uvec i +B_y \uvec j$